# Modern good-guy vampire, female night-beat reporter?

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

There's a movie I think in the 90s that I can't name and can't find anywhere.  There's a vampire that's a pretty good guy I think and a night-beat reporter.  I think she was tipped onto him by strange things going on at night and it seems like is trying to get a story about vampires being real and will out him as a vampire.  There's also a mad scientist type that finds out he is a vampire and wants to do some sort of experiment on him.  The mad scientist ends up trapping him and I think he wakes up in a vault with the female reporter.  He's grown fond of her and doesn't want to feed on her but he is weak and tempted because it's been a long time since he could feed.

> The reporter wants to let him feed but he uses his power to hide so she can't get to him.  She finds him though because he is weak and lets him feed.  It turns out she is a vampire too and will be OK, and he gets so much power he busts open the vault door.

Comment: *Vampire Cop* maybe? There's a vampire (cop), a reporter who also turns out to be a vampire...

Comment: There is a Canadian TV series called Forever Knight that fits some of this description, certainly 90s, vampire cop and reporter.

Comment: @user23614 - Which actually was originally a movie, *Nick Knight*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took me looking over [a lot](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls052565463/) vampire movies, but I found it.  I had a couple details wrong, but the movie is ["Pale Blood"](http://www.tvguide.com/movies/pale-blood/review/128909/), a [1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blood) direct-to-vhs movie starring George Chakiris, Wings Hauser, and Pamela Ludwig.

I had a couple of details wrong.  The "good guy" vampire does believe in drinking the least he needs so not to endanger the person.  The "night-beat reporter" is really an investigator with an interest in vampires he hires to help him get to the bottom of some murders that occurred where people were drained of blood.

> The bad guy that locks him in a vault lined with garlic and crucifixes is a "video artist" that wants to capture a vampire feeding on film and has done the killings himself to lure a vampire for that purpose.